# How JavaScript uses variables when reading json

Tags: javascript, json

Like the title, I tried to use variables when reading json, but it didn't work (

```
fetch('https://lolimstatic.ml/counts/apis.json').then(
(response) => {
    response.json().then((data) => {
        const apiListFrame = document.querySelector('#als');
        const api = document.createElement('a');
        api.classList.add('btns');
        api.classList.add('button');
        api.classList.add('apilist');
        var rns = Math.round(Math.random()*10);
        colors = ["blue","red","white","orange","pink","green","yellow","skyblue","purple","gray"];
        api.style.background = colors[rns];
        api.style.width = '200px';
        var lstd = Math.round(Math.random()*data[0].counts);
        api.href = 'https://docs.lolimapis.ml/API/'+ data[0].list[lstd] +'/';
        lnm = data[0].list[lstd];
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open("GET", 'https://lolimstatic.ml/counts/apis/zh.json');
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState = 4) {
                const res = xhr.responseText;
                // Here is variables Json
                api.innerText = res.lnm;
                apiListFrame.appendChild(api);
            }
        }
    })
}
)
```

I think it read to this:

```
{
    "lnm": ""
}
```

But I want read to this(Suppose the lnm variable is BingImage):

```
{
    "BingImage": "每日Bing图获取"
}
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean but are you asking how to get the data from your `json` and use it in your `JS` code?

Comment: Can you show us what you get when you console log your `data` object

Comment: What is the value of `xhr.responseType` when the ready state change handler is called? If it's "json", `xhr.response` is the data object, not  `xhr.responseText`. See [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) documentation for details

Comment: lnm is a variable, but javascript thinks it is a json object, I want it to be used as a variable

Comment: ![](https://i.bmp.ovh/imgs/2022/03/7846f6bc573d17c0.png)

Comment: You need to parse the `JSON` so javaScript can use it.

Comment: @Sebastian Gbudje         https://i.bmp.ovh/imgs/2022/03/bdbd9f932f798c6d.png

Answer (score 0):

Once you make the Ajax call, you parse the `JSON` and are now able to use it.

```js
fetch('https://lolimstatic.ml/counts/apis.json').then(
(response) => {
    response.json().then((data) => {
        const apiListFrame = document.querySelector('#als');
        const api = document.createElement('a');
        api.classList.add('btns');
        api.classList.add('button');
        api.classList.add('apilist');
        var rns = Math.round(Math.random()*10);
        colors = ["blue","red","white","orange","pink","green","yellow","skyblue","purple","gray"];
        api.style.background = colors[rns];
        api.style.width = '200px';
        var lstd = Math.round(Math.random()*data[0].counts);
        api.href = 'https://docs.lolimapis.ml/API/'+ data[0].list[lstd] +'/';
        lnm = data[0].list[lstd];
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open("GET", 'https://lolimstatic.ml/counts/apis/zh.json');
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // Here is us parsing the JSON
                const res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);;
                // Here is variables Json
                api.innerText = res.GitHubUserInfo;
                apiListFrame.appendChild(api);
            }
        }
    })
}
)
```

Comment: It return this(   <a class="btns button apilist" href="https://docs.lolimapis.ml/API/GitHubUserCard/" style="background: pink; width: 200px;">undefined</a>

Comment: Change `xhr.readyState = 4 ` to `xhr.readyState == 4` also `console.log(res)` and post the result.

Comment: @XiaMoHuaHuo_CN this is what was inside your `JSON` data set there is no `lnm`
`163Music: "网易云音乐解析"
ACGPic: "随机二次元图"
AcFunVideo: "AcFun视频直链解析"
BiliBiliUserInfo: "BiliBili用户信息获取"
BingImage: "每日Bing图获取"
CatFoxGirl: "随机猫娘/狐狸图"
GitHubUserCard: "GitHub签名档"
GitHubUserInfo: "GitHub用户信息获取"
GoogleDrive: "GoogleDrive直链解析"
KuGouMusic: "酷狗音乐解析"
KuWoMusic: "酷我音乐解析"
LanZouDrive: "蓝奏云直链解析"
MCServerQuery: "Minecraft服务器信息查询"
QQGroupAvatar: "QQ群头像获取"
QQUserAvatar: "QQ头像获取"
QRCode: "QRCode生成"
RealUrl: "短链接还原"`

Comment: If you use any of the data in that comment inside your code, you should see it's value. I'll edit the above answer to show you.

Comment: Thanks (: But can I create more buttons?

Comment: You can create more buttons and have them have different `JSON` data. There are quite a number of ways to do so. You can easily turn your data to an array and then use `map()` and add them to a button. ALso if you found the answer helpful please give it an upvote